# Is it possible to embed Jedi in an application on a system where Python is not installed?

Tags: python, autocomplete, subprocess, scintilla, python-jedi

I'm working on an (Windows and Mac) application that [uses Python as an embedded scripting language](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).

The application includes an internal text editor, implemented using [Scintilla](https://www.scintilla.org/), and I'm using [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for autocompletion, which generally works great.

However, when attempting autocompletion on a computer that does not have a separate installation of Python, Jedi raises an error:

> `jedi.api.environment.InvalidPythonEnvironment`:
>
> Could not get version information for 'python':
>
> `FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)`

Digging into the code, I can see that [the underlying code that is throwing](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/9617d4527de583b0b900166e4430a8964ee67dc6/jedi/evaluate/compiled/subprocess/__init__.py#L170) the `FileNotFoundError` is when Jedi attempts to run `python` using `subprocess.Popen`. Python is not installed on the computer, so this fails.

I can also reproduce the same issue on a computer that *does* have Python installed by editing my `Path` environment variable not to include the location of `python.exe`.

Ideally, we don't want users of our application to have to install Python just to get autocompletion working.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to get Jedi *not* to spawn subprocesses, and instead run its code inside the same instance of Python within which it itself is running? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation or the source code that deals with Environments, and extrapolating from the [discussion here](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/870) I suspect the answer might be no.
2. Is it possible somehow to get Jedi to use the same `python37.dll` that our application is using for its functionality, instead of looking for a `.exe` file that does not exist?
3. Is there any way we could make some kind of minimal Python installation within our existing app installation that uses the same DLLs/Python Lib etc? How could I go about doing this?
4. Is there any other way to get Jedi autocompletion working in our app without requiring the user to install Python, or including a full Python installer as part of our build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it possible to get Jedi not to spawn subprocesses, and instead run its code inside the same instance of Python within which it itself is running? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation or the source code that deals with Environments, and extrapolating from the discussion here I suspect the answer might be no.

This is definitely possible. All the tools are there. There are discussions ongoing here: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/870.

IMO a patch to Jedi is needed that uses an `jedi.api.environment.InterpreterEnvironment` in some cases like yours. It's definitely possible, it's just buggy at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! I think I must have misinterpreted some of the linked discussion when I read it before: I thought it was simply about finding the *correct* path to the executable, rather than about not requiring the executable to exist at all. I'll read it more carefully now. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is, in there we just know that `sys.executable` is wrong. This is a case we need to properly handle in Jedi (and not jedi-vim).

Comment: For posterity's sake, I think option 3 is also most likely possible and is probably preferable, if I could have got it working? I tried simply copying the `python.exe` built by `build.bat` into my app's installation and passing its path into `jedi.create_environment()`. It got a bit further, but then raised an even more inscrutable error in the `pickle_load` call. After failing to diagnose that for a bit I gave up and tried just passing `jedi.api.environment.InterpreterEnvironment()` into the `Script` constructor, and so far that appears to work fine.